# I am not getting data passed from controller to my view in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC, used to work with Web APIs.

I have confronted with a problem that does not allow me to fetch data to my view coming from the controller.

As soon as I change the object I am returning (string for example), the code works just fine.

I have the following model class:

```
public class Personnel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PayrollNumber { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surename { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Telephone { get; set; }
    public int Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string EmailHome { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDataContext _context;

    public UploadController(IDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("Index")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream());

        var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<PersonnelClassMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Personnel>();
        await _context.Personnel.AddRangeAsync(records);
        await _context.ContextSaveChanges();

        return View(records); 
    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Web.Models.Personnel>

<div class="card">

    <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4">
        Records inserted
    </h3>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div id="table" class="table-editable">
            <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
                <a href="#!" class="text-success"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </span>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @{
                            var properties = typeof(Personnel).GetProperties();
                            foreach (var property in properties)
                            {
                                if (property.Name == "Id")
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                <th scope="col">@property.Name</th>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                        {
                        foreach (var record in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@record.Surename</td>

                                    <td class="pt-3-half">
                                        <span class="table-up">
                                            <a href="#!" class="indigo-text"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="table-down">
                                            <a href="#!" class="indigo-text"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="table-remove">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">
                                                Remove
                                            </button>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, I am not getting the value from the model, I also tried `ViewData` and `ViewBag`, but those do not work either.

My guess is that has something to do with the CSV reader.

Comment: What type is your model? Some kind of collection of `Personnel`? Where have you defined this type in your view?

Comment: yes I just forgot to add this line here, Model is IEnumerable<Personnel>

Comment: You mean you cannot get the value of the Personnel model in the view?

Comment: I am passing the List<Personnel> to view, and define the Model IEnumerable<Personnel> that should match and allow to fetch the data, but for some reason it does not.

Comment: But in your index() `public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }` you pass nothing to the view.

Comment: Do you try `return View( _context.Personnel.ToList());`?

Comment: I do not see a <form> tag in your HTML that is needed to POST data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think that you are getting confused here. You first ActionMethod- `Index` is by default `HttpGet` so this method will be responsible to get your data and assign it to your `View`, so you need to change your method to:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<Personnel> allRecords = _context.Personnel.ToList();
    //Here we are sending our Model of type List<Personnel> to the View
    return View(allRecords);
}
```

And the `View` will expect to receive model of type `List<Personnel>`:

```
@model List<Web.Models.Personnel>

<div class="card">

    <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4">
        Records inserted
    </h3>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div id="table" class="table-editable">
            <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
                <a href="#!" class="text-success"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </span>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @{
                            var properties = typeof(Personnel).GetProperties();
                            foreach (var property in properties)
                            {
                                if (property.Name == "Id")
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                <th scope="col">@property.Name</th>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                        {
                        foreach (var record in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">@record.Surename</td>

                                    <td class="pt-3-half">
                                        <span class="table-up">
                                            <a href="#!" class="indigo-text"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="table-down">
                                            <a href="#!" class="indigo-text"><i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="table-remove">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">
                                                Remove
                                            </button>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now your second ActionMethod is of type `HttpPost` so for that you need to enclose your elements in a `form` and then do a submit with the required data to this method.